# Observer class must be declared abstract or implement an abstract method

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I want to use RxAndroid and RxJava in my project. But as shown in the below code, in getAnimalsObserver() method, the following line:

```
return new Observer<String>
```

is underscored with a red line saying:  //class must be either declared abstract or implement abstract method
please let me know how to fix that error.

**code**:
    import rx.Observable;
    import rx.Observer;
    import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
    import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

```
//class must be either declared abstract or implement abstract method
private Observer<String> getAnimalsObserver() {
    return new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Name: " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, "All items are emitted!");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you import the correct `Observer` interface?

Answer (score 1):

This is the `Observer` interface you are implementing:

```
public interface Observer<T> {

    void onCompleted();

    void onError(Throwable e);

    void onNext(T t);

}
```

As you can see, it's `onCompleted()` not `onComplete()`.

Tip: With the cursor inside the body of your implementation class, press `Ctrl+I`, Android Studio IDE will show dialog with available class members to implement.